# iTunes and Unicode ID3 Tags

Tags: itunes, mp3, unicode, id3

I'm using [MP3Tag](http://www.mp3tag.de/en/) for tagging my MP3s since a long time and it creates very good results.

With iTunes (of course not with other MP3 programs e.g. Winamp) I always have problems after first import of my MP3 files with unicode. After the first import they look like this:

[image]

After the first play they are actually displayed correctly (see the image below the line). I have found no feature in iTunes to mass "identify" the correct ID3 tags instead of the crappy first job after import - I have to play the song or hit "Get Info" for each song to clear everything up.

My MP3 Files are encoded with ID3 v 2.4 with UTF-8 - apparently iTunes doesn't have a problem with it because after playing the song, everything is fine - it is only the import making a problem.

Second problem is that for almost all songs the song title is at first  -  and only after the first play it becomes .

---

1. How to correctly format ID3 Tags, so iTunes will recognize them directly upon import?
2. Which tool is out there to "loop through all songs in the iTunes DB and clean them up?

On the second one I use "iTunes Folder Watch" which is perfect for synchronizing a local folder to your iTunes library.

Comment: So, what is your question?

Comment: Sorry I added the question :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. No idea. Never had this problem (I use Winamp and [TagScanner](http://www.xdlab.ru/en/) to tag), but I mainly deal with lossless M4A. Anyway, perhaps check the options for saving ID3tags in MP3Tag and try different things. Maybe you'll find a setting iTunes works well with. If you auto-tag them in Winamp, does iTunes import them correctly?
2. When I do a change (eg. using TagScanner) to files already in my iTunes library, I just select all files concerned and change something that is not used, such as Grouping or Composer. This action will force iTunes to open all files and it will update them. Alternatively, open the property pages and clicking next repeateadly (or just holding ALT+N) should also update them.

Comment: Winamp does everything perfect. I don't want to play around as I think iTunes should support ID3 v 2.4 tags - I just don't know whether there is something else going wrong. I'll look into TagScanner. Oh, and I love the "I will just add something random to force iTunes to reload the files" - good that it works that way, but seriously that is not how one should do it :-)

Comment: @moontear Right, a "refresh" option would be much nicer. The invidual property page method (ALT+N) is faster for one or 2 albums, and doesn't require adding junk.